# Why does the Riemannian volume form not follow the pattern of including derivatives?

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

The arc-lenght integral can be expressed as the inner product:

$$
\int \sqrt{\mathbf{g}_\tau \cdot \mathbf{g}_\tau}d\tau \tag{1}
$$

where $\mathbf{g}_\tau$ is a vector of the tangent space of a manifold M. Then using the replacement procedure $\mathbf{g}_\tau =\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} \gamma(\tau) $ we get

$$
\int \sqrt{\frac{\partial \gamma_\mu(\tau)}{\partial \tau}\frac{\partial \gamma^\nu(\tau)}{\partial \tau}}  d\tau
$$

which is the familiar arclength integral.

Then, reading this article, https://web.science.uu.nl/itf/Teaching/2009/Mischa%20Spelt.pdf, the author recovers the Nambu-goto action using geometric algebra by defining a surface integral:

$$
S=\iint \sqrt{(\mathbf{g}_\tau \wedge \mathbf{g}_\sigma)^2}d\tau d\sigma \tag{2}
$$

where $\sqrt{(\mathbf{g}_\tau \wedge \mathbf{g}_\sigma)^2}$ is the area associated with the vectors $\mathbf{g}_\tau$ and $\mathbf{g}_\sigma$. Taking these vectors to be elements of some tangent space of $M$, the replacement $\mathbf{g}_\tau=\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau }x(\tau,\sigma)$ and $\mathbf{g}_\tau=\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma }x(\tau,\sigma)$ and with some causual algebraic manipulations, eventually produces the Nambu-Goto action (Page 25):

$$
S=\int \sqrt{ \left( \frac{\partial x^\mu(\tau,\sigma)}{\partial \tau}\frac{\partial x_\nu(\tau,\sigma)}{\partial \sigma} \right)^2 - \left( \frac{\partial x^\mu(\tau,\sigma)}{\partial \tau}\frac{\partial x_\nu(\tau,\sigma)}{\partial \sigma} \right) \left( \frac{\partial x^\mu(\tau,\tau)}{\partial \sigma}\frac{\partial x_\nu(\tau,\sigma)}{\partial \sigma} \right)}d\tau d\sigma \tag{3}
$$

---

One can identify a progression from arc-lengh to area to volume to 4-volume by jamming more wedge products. For instance one can write the volume form as :

$$
\iiint \sqrt{(\mathbf{g}_x \wedge \mathbf{g}_y \wedge \mathbf{g}_z)^2} dxdydz
$$

and the 4-volume:

$$
\iiiint \sqrt{(\mathbf{g}_x \wedge \mathbf{g}_y \wedge \mathbf{g}_z \wedge \mathbf{g}_t)^2} dxdydzdt
$$

My question relates to the 4-volume and why the replacements from $\mathbf{g}$ to their derivative formulation play no role, while they do in 1 or 2 dimensions. For example, consider the following integral:

$$
\iiiint \sqrt{|\det g_{\mu\nu}|} d^4x
$$

This integral is the consequence of taking

$$
\iiiint \sqrt{(\mathbf{e}_0\wedge \mathbf{e}_1 \wedge \mathbf{e}_2  \wedge \mathbf{e}_0 )^2}d^4x=\iiiint \sqrt{(\sqrt{|\det g_{\mu\nu}
|}\gamma_0\wedge \gamma_1 \wedge \gamma_2  \wedge \gamma_0 )^2}d^4x=\iiiint (\sqrt{|\det g_{\mu\nu}
|}d^4x \tag{4}
$$

So now, I am questioning why are we not using the same definition for lower dimensions. For instance, in the case of (2), can we not just write:

$$
\iint \sqrt{\mathbf{g}_\tau \wedge \mathbf{g}_\sigma}d\tau d \sigma=\iint \sqrt{|\det g^{\mu\nu}|}d \tau \sigma \tag{5}
$$

What do the derivatives give us that the determinant doesn't? What does (3) give us that (5) doesn't?

Or, form the other direction, why would I not define the volume form (4) by replacing the vectors $\mathbf{e}_u$ with derivatives, and what would I gain/lose by doing so? Why (4) and not have a 4-volume form as:

$$
\iiiint \sqrt{\left( \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} \wedge \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} \wedge \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}  \wedge \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} \right)^2}dxdydzdt
$$

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want here.  You seem to understand that the two definitions are equivalent, so you can use whichever is more convenient in any given context.

Comment: @EricWofsey I think I understand it as follows: If you embed a manifold in a larger space, you use the differential form to account for the embedding. If instead, you take the integral of a D-field in D-space then the derivatives can be posed equal to 1 (because there are no embedding) and thus you recover the usual Riemann volume form (without derivatives). Which is why general relativity has the usual Riemann volume form, and string theory has the one with the derivatives.